# Visual Basic - Removing values from FOR Loop

Tags: visual-studio, for-loop

I managed to create a loop in Visual Basic that duplicates numbers. So 122333444455555, etc.

```
  Dim u As Long, j As Long

  For u = 1 To 5
        For j = 1 To u
              Console.Write(u)
        Next j
  Next u
```

Now, I would like to create a `For` loop, like the one above, but in this case it only includes 1,333,55555. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Add a "Step" to your FOR clause.  For u = 1 to 5 step 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) option in your outer for loop to make it count by twos, thereby only giving you the odd numbers:

```
Sub Main()
    For u As Long = 1 To 5 Step 2
        For j As Long = 1 To u
            Console.Write(u)
        Next j
    Next u

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.Write("Press any key to quit...")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Output:

```
133355555
Press any key to quit...
```

An alternative would be leave your outer loop counting by one, and then only execute the inner loop for odd numbers using the [Mod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator) operator:

```
For u As Long = 1 To 5
    If (u Mod 2) = 1 Then ' only work with odd "u" values
        For j As Long = 1 To u
            Console.Write(u)
        Next j
    End If
Next u
```

I'd recommend this approach only if you needed to do something different when "u" is an even number (add an `Else` block to handle those cases).

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't even think about that!